# Jmeter thread per url

Tags: url, testing, web, jmeter, load

I have one project to test load balancers algorithms for web cluster and I decide to use Jmeter but am stuck since am not experienced with it and on Internet I see different cases and scenarios which are not detailed described (steps hot to achieve them).

In test environment I have 5 generic websites (web1.com, web2.com, web3.com, web4.com and web5.com).

Test cases which I want to perform are:

CASE1: Linear and proportional web load - by other words I want to check web1 5 times in row then web1 and web2 5x, then web1,web2, web3 5x, then, web1-4 5x and then on the end all 5 websites 5x. To see how computer recurses and web nodes will perform in this proportional load. As far as I know this should be done by 5 different threads but I cant define URL per website or time when it will start to load other websites as well. I have tried with dataset (cvs) but I can achieve that parallel website check because in CVS I can only add one website under another as list...

CASE2: In this case I would like to set my own "random numbers" for example to send website check in "random order": web2,web2,web5,web1,web3,web4,web1,web1 ... Reason for this is because I want to simulate "real case" by other words real "clicks by end users" which are not linear... (I want to keep "random list" because I want to perform same random check on several different LB algorithms).

I would be very great full if you have any described steps or any screen shots.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The First:
You want a `Loop` with an `If` with your requests inside that:

[image: testplan]
This will give you give you the 1,1,2,1,2,3... that you want. You have two options from there: if you want exactly what you described, surround `Web1` to the last `If` with a loop. What I think you want though, is simply 5 users doing this simultaneously.

The Second is very easy:
Look at the [Random Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller). You'll put each of your requests inside it, and it inside a loop.

Comment: First of all thanks for your fast replay. I have mange to copy/paste what you made on picture but am stuck again since am not that familiar with Jmeter, I have few questions: 1. On picture object "Depeth" is loop controller? 2. How  will IF work in this case, when will it start with Web2, Web3 etc.. I was hoping I will be able to define when "2nd user (web2)" will start and same procedure for the rest of the webs.

Comment: Regarding CASE2: I want to define my random "http request list" in some CVS maybe or something but also with multi thread because I want to perform those predefine random request on several different LB algorithms. If you could share more screens or even attachment if it is possible I would be very thankful.